# Am I interacting with the original object?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

Ok still learning here. If I have one form calling another form like below (only the code for the second form is listed) where the parent form is ParentForm and I make a private member _parentForm in teh child form (`frmViewPastMeasures` ) so I can use it all over my child form class. If when I call _parentForm.Method() from my child form and that method is trying to change properties in the original parent form...are those properties affected in the same parentform I called from? Does `_parentForm = parentForm;` link `_parentForm` to the *exact* same object as `parentForm`? Is the only time when that would not be the case be when I use the `new` keyword? I just trying to change properties from an outside form and I want to make sure I'm actually accomplishing this correctly.

```
namespace Photometer
{
    public partial class frmViewPastMeasures : Form
    {
        private frmPhotometer _parentForm;

        public frmViewPastMeasures(csFilter activeFilter, csInitialUsageSettings InitialUsageSettings, frmPhotometer parentForm)
        {
            _parentForm = parentForm;
        }
        private someOtherMethod()
        {
            _parentForm.method();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes if you assign the parent form to a local var, that is a reference and you always manipulate the same object. If you use the new keyword you create another one and they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, if you assign an object reference to a variable, that variable will point to the exact same object as the one to which the assigned reference pointed.